# Design REST API for Mobile Apps with Unregister Users

Tags: design, api, authentication

I'd like to know some best practices on how to build rest API for a backend which shall communicate with a mobile app by anonymous users.

This is the scenario with details:

I'm building a demo library app that shows details about books, those details are returned in a JSON format when the app fetches the URL

`www.mylibrary.com/<bookid>/details`

Anyone having the App installed should be able to fetch any book details without registering in the app.

The response is generated from an API Gateway and a lambda function in AWS, which reads from DynamoDB.

---

Is there any way to, let's say, avoid that a user cURLs or browses the endpoint `www.mylibrary.com/<bookid>/details` and gets the JSON response?

How, for example, an app like Amazon or Reddit handles the fetching of its product catalogue/posts from the app?

If anonymous users can fetch JSON from Amazon's endpoint, let's say `amazon.com/catalog?country=us` and display it on a mobile screen, does it mean that I can browse to that URL and get the same JSON response?

Is there any other clever "protection/approach" to avoid exposing the JSON to any device?